# Force serial mySQL insertions (or rebuild a table a better way)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

I'm new to mySQL transactions and I'm working with some code that I inherited, but the question is more fundamental capability related than code specific.

- I have a js array that I want to insert into a mySQL table.  The
  table size will never exceed 200 entries, most often fewer than 100.
- Presently, I'm looping through the js array and sending individual
  AJAX requests for each array element to an existing PHP file that
  processes them as they arrive and does the sql INSERT call for each
  element.  async is set to 'false' in the js AJAX call.
- Everything is working successfully – no INSERTS fail and no data is
  lost so this isn't a code failure question – but when I later get the table
  from the database and load it into an array, ordered by updated (added), the sequence of the entries is wrong, and that's an issue.

So my question to the mySQL experts is this: is there a simple handshake function I'm not seeing that will ensure that mySQL insertions are processed in order?

If the answer is no, I will need to add a sequence number to each request and add a column for it in the table. Also, if I'm going to make changes to the inherited code anyway, I'm open to pointers on what to look into for a more efficient solution.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest solution to your problem would be to set an auto_increment primary key column in your table. That way a new id (lastID+1) will be generated on each insert and the they will be correctly ordered.

Comment: Why a request per element? You can send the complete array in a single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paul Spiegel has said it's better to use an auto_increment if all you want is a repeatable sequence of events.

I am assuming that when you say 'order by updated (added)' then that is a DateTime field or some such on the table. If your inserts happen fast enough then there will be multiple rows on the same insert date/time (the field only goes to One Second resolution) and MySQL doesn't guarantee you will always get the rows back in the same order when that happens.

Comment: I didn't say that. Though I would, if Ivan86 didn't. :-)

Comment: Yes, this was the problem.  Not enough resolution on the updated time field.  Works fine for individual updates (but it's still the wrong design) but not for bulk inputs.  I changed it to use an auto_increment field and all is good.  Next step is to evolve to the suggestion from Kosh Very  for better performance and cleaner design.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert all your array at once:

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
>   do this, include multiple lists of comma-separated column values, with
>   lists enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Read more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Comment: Yes, this is where I will be taking it when I can get to it.  The performance of individual row processing is not impressive.   Thanks!

Comment: Not only the performance. You can keep the original order of the entries as well.

Comment: Yes, it's the right way to do it.  Without question.